# how to find the sum of the n largest values by group of values in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

A DataFrame has two columns
groups "grps" and values "vals":

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'grps': list('aaabbcaabcccbbc'), 
                   'vals': [12,345,3,1,45,14,4,52,54,23,235,21,57,3,87]})
```

for each group, i have to find the sum of the three largest values. 
I should end up with a dataframe as follows:

```
grps
a    409
b    156
c    345
```

i have tried this but it does not work :

```
df.groupby('grps').nlargest(3, 'vals').sum()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this expression:

```py
df.groupby('grps').apply(lambda x: x.vals.nlargest(3).sum())
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to `apply`:

```
df.groupby('grps')['vals'].nlargest(3).sum(level=0)
```